# Why I get Parent table's ID as many times as it matches child table records

Tags: sql, database, join

Here is sample schema:

```
create table parent_tab
( id int primary key,
name varchar2(100));

create table child_tab
( id int primary key,
name varchar2(100),
parent_id int references parent_tab(id));


insert into parent_tab values (1,'One');
insert into parent_tab values (2,'Two');

insert into child_tab values (11,'abc',1);
insert into child_tab values (12,'def',1);
insert into child_tab values (13,'ghi',1);
insert into child_tab values (14,'jkl',1);

insert into child_tab values (15,'mno',2);
insert into child_tab values (16,'pqr',2);
insert into child_tab values (17,'stu',2);
insert into child_tab values (18,'vwx',2);
```

I use below query to extract `ID` from `parent_Tab` if it has any child records.

```
select p.id 
from parent_Tab p 
inner join child_tab c on p.id = c.parent_id ;
```

**Current Output:**

```
ID
___
1                                      
1                                      
1                                      
1                                      
2                                      
2                                      
2                                      
2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ID
___
1                                                                 
2
```

What I exactly I want to know is **Why it's duplicated?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using `INNER JOIN`. So, It returns the what are all the matching records. 
Here you can include `DISTINCT` to get the expected result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id 
FROM parent_Tab p 
INNER JOIN child_tab c ON p.id = c.parent_id ;
```

Comment: Can you explain why duplicates ?

Comment: INNER JOINS return all rows from multiple tables where the join condition is met. In table 1 you have 2 records but in table 2 you have multiple records for the 2 parent id. So, When ever you used the inner join it will returns the all the matched  rows.